# When should I prefer @classmethod over a @staticmethod and vice versa?

Tags: python, static-methods, class-method

**Note:** this question is not about

- "How can I use `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod`?" or
- "What is the difference between `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod`?"

---

In the following classes,

1. both `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` can access a class attribute.
2. neither of them can access instance attributes.

**MyClass1.py**

```
class MyClass1:
    __module_attr: str = "initial text value"

    def __init__(self):
        self.__instance_attr: str = "instance text value"

    @classmethod
    def cls_modify(cls):
        cls.__module_attr = "class text value"

    @staticmethod
    def stat_display():
        print(MyClass1.__module_attr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_obj = MyClass1()
    my_obj.stat_display()
    my_obj.cls_modify()
    my_obj.stat_display()
```

**MyClass2.py**

```
class MyClass2:
    module_attr: str = "initial text value"

    def __init__(self):
        self.__instance_attr: str = "instance text value"

    @classmethod
    def cls_modify(cls):
        cls.module_attr = "class text value"

    @staticmethod
    def stat_display():
        print(MyClass2.module_attr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_obj = MyClass2()
    my_obj.stat_display()
    my_obj.cls_modify()
    my_obj.stat_display()
    print(my_obj.module_attr)
    print(MyClass2.module_attr)
```

So, I can't see any advantage of one type over another.

When should I prefer `@classmethod` over a `@staticmethod` and vice versa?

Comment: The difference is that the class method gets the class as the first argument, whereas you hardcode the class name in the static method. This makes a difference for inheritance.

Comment: My rule of thumb is: if it uses neither `self` nor the class, then: 1) is it really a method or rather an independent function? And 2) if it still makes sense as a method, then mark it as `@staticmethod` to make it explicit that it uses neither. In every other case, it’s a regular method or a class method.

Comment: @deceze, what if the method accesses a class-attribute, but no instance attribute?

Comment: Is it supposed to be *called on the class*? Then it’s by necessity a class method. If it’s supposed to be called on an instance, then it’s a normal method. I can’t really think of a useful example of an instance method that only manipulates the class though. You’ll probably know it when you need it.

Comment: @deceze, I need to store a dictionary in a class where each instance of the class should be able to access the dictionary. The dictionary contains hundreds of objects. As a result, that dictionary is memory-intensive.

So, I can keep the dictionary as a private class attribute and access that using either a `classmethod` or a `staticmethod`.

Which type should I use?

Comment: You can access class attributes just fine from instances as well, that in itself is no criterion whatsoever.